# Unexpected missing value on left join

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table `players` with an id and a name row. I also have a `possessions` table with a foreign `player_id` and an amount of things they own. I want to list the possessions of all players. Since some players do not have possessions, I thought the right tool would be a left join (the players being left):

```sql
SELECT players.nickname, possessions.amount
FROM players LEFT JOIN possessions ON possessions.player_id = players.id
```

Which looks right (foo owns several different things, bar doesn't own anything):

[image]

Now I want to sum the amount. I tried both SUM() and TOTAL(), both filter out `bar`. I tried forcing the NULL to a 0 with coalesce and some CASE statements. But the "bar" player disappears every time:

```
SELECT players.nickname, total(possessions.amount)
FROM players LEFT JOIN possessions ON possessions.player_id = players.id
```

[image]

My assumption is that things get filtered by the ON clause maybe? But it seems to go through in the above results, so I don't understand.

TL;DR: I want "bar" listed with 0 amount, it doesn't appear in the right table.

Comment: Have you tried 'isnull(posessions.amount,0)'

Comment: can you share the query having the SUM/TOTAL?

Comment: @KennethChirchir sure, I added it. Nathan you mean IFNULL? Yes... still filtered out

Comment: Can you show how you tried to handle the nulls?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav already solved, see answer below. I need a group by statement apparently.

Comment: No worries, so looks like you'd not handled the null after all then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `COALESCE()` here, to report the sum as zero for any nickname having no possessions.  But, your query has another problem too, and should be using `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT p.nickname, COALESCE(SUM(po.amount), 0) AS amount
FROM players p
LEFT JOIN possessions po ON po.player_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.nickname;
```

Comment: huh, that GROUP BY alone did it. Thanks.. I still have to learn apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `SUM()` nor `TOTAL()` are filtering out anything. You get only one result row because the query is missing a GROUP BY-clause.

The difference between the two functions is

- `SUM()` returns `NULL` when only NULL values ​​are summed.
- `TOTAL()` returns `0` even if only NULL values ​​are summed.

We can see this in this query (note that it does not use `COALESCE`):

```sql
SELECT
  players.nickname,
  SUM(possessions.amount) AS sum_amount,
  TOTAL(possessions.amount) AS total_amount
FROM
  players
  LEFT JOIN possessions
    ON players.id = possessions.player_id
GROUP BY players.nickname
ORDER BY players.id
```

It returns

| nickname | sum_amount | total_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 5 | 5 |
| bar | NULL | 0 |

The `TOTAL()` function is specific to SQLite.

As a general rule, you must include all columns that are listed in the SELECT-list or are used in the WHERE-clause or ORDER BY-clause in the GROUP BY-clause, except when an aggregate function (`SUM`, `COUNT`, `MIN`, `MAX`, etc.) is applied to a column.